# observe foreground applications in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

It is somehow possible to observe foreground applications in Windows Phone 8?
Observe the name of the opened app and maybe time of opening and closing.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's no API in the WP8 SDK that would return that information. If that's a feature you'd like to see in future releases go to the [wpdev uservoice](http://wpdev.uservoice.com), explain you usecase and get developers to vote on it.